# Jasmin Interceptor

Tags: sms, interceptor, sms-gateway, smpp, jasmin-sms

I am just sharpening my skills on SMS services and now a days I am trying to configuring JASMIN for this purpose.

I have installed jasmin SMS and GUI interface PlaySMS on ubuntu 18.04. I am also successful using SMS service to send sms using SMPP and now I want to go into more details. I want to grep SMS attributes and set some set of rules before sending it to the provider. For this purpose I wanted to know how to use interceptor with JASMIN and to configure the same.

I have referred https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/  for this. But here, I am not getting such file https://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interception/index.html

Here  are some logs, which indicate successful connection with interceptor.

```
2020-05-11 15:01:50 INFO     8354 Interceptor configured and ready.
2020-05-11 15:01:51 INFO     8354 Authenticated Avatar: iadmin
```

As per reference link, I have also added some filter for MT route in jasmin. Here is the configuration for this.

```
#Order Type                    Rate       Connector ID(s)                                  Filter(s)
#102   StaticMTRoute           3.45000    smppc(smpptest)                                  <TG (tag=21403)>
#101   StaticMTRoute           1.36000    smppc(smppclient1)                               <TG (tag=21401)>
#100   StaticMTRoute
```

Now, when I try to send sms, it's working but interceptor is not coming in picture any way.
If anyone can correct me with what is wrong with my configuration or any other idea to fulfill my need, please let me know.

Here I am also sharing my SMPP log.

SMPP Log :

````
2020-05-07 16:54:34 INFO     934 SMS-MT [cid:smpptest] [queue-msgid:af4e11d7-d83b-4988-9ee8-c0de955554b3] [smpp-msgid:8fcc3dab-d715-41fd-9cac-6f1bb2ec5b0a] [status:ESME_ROK] [prio:0] [dlr:SMSC_DELIVERY_RECEIPT_REQUESTED] [validity:none] [from:006542] [to:8965475636] [content:'Hi u there, good morning!! \x00admin']

2020-05-07 16:57:45 INFO     934 SMS-MT [cid:smpptest] [queue-msgid:1f58e285-a64d-4fb0-ae96-8f0f2ad6a4ee] [smpp-msgid:e6aa27cc-9b30-4878-8463-096f2949e0ae] [status:ESME_ROK] [prio:0] [dlr:SMSC_DELIVERY_RECEIPT_REQUESTED] [validity:none] [from:006542] [to:+21401896324] [content:'Hello , please hurry up, boss summons us ! \x00admin']
2020-05-07 16:59:42 INFO     934 SMS-MT [cid:smpptest] [queue-msgid:c112affd-7932-4f88-b20d-d5164fddbb72] [smpp-msgid:f0bbfdd2-ef91-4262-93b4-e5ba63cef259] [status:ESME_ROK] [prio:0] [dlr:SMSC_DELIVERY_RECEIPT_REQUESTED] [validity:none] [from:006542] [to:21401963874] [content:'Hello , please hurry up, boss summons us ! \x00admin']```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the Interceptor

```
sudo systemctl start jasmin-interceptord
```

You can also view the status by checking the logs at

```
/var/log/jasmin/interceptor.log
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks For reply.

Yes, I have already fire this command. But i think nothing to be happen. also I have share logs on above which I see.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an **interception rule** as well as an **interception file** (a python file)?

**Interceptor file example (/opt/jasmin-scripts/interception/mt-interceptor.py)**

```
routable.pdu.params['source_addr'] = 'NewSource'
routable.lockPduParam('source_addr')
```

**Interceptor rule example (in Jasmin SMS Gateway's CLI)**

```
telnet <ip> <port>
mtinterceptor -a
type DefaultInterceptor
script python3(/opt/jasmin-scripts/interception/mt-interceptor.py)
ok
persist
quit
```

You might need to restart the Jasmin SMS interceptor as well

```
sudo systemctl start jasmin-interceptord
```